# RabbitMQ - cannot delete queue because the queue cannot be found

Tags: rabbitmq, rabbitmqctl

Overnight our RabbitMQ queues got full. The node basically ran out of space. However now RabbitMQ doesn't really work. No component can make a connection to it, because it blocks connections. I want to free up the space under it, but when I try to purge a queue via the admin gui, I get the following error:

> NOT_FOUND - no queue 'sharding: sharded_queue - rabbit@hostname - 0'
> in vhost '/'

If I try to list the queues with the command line tool, they are not listed. These ques are only visible at this moment via the GUI, but I cannot interact with them in any way. Delete doesn't work either.

Is there a way, a workaround to get the queues cleaned? Should I find the actual messages stored on the disk and delete those?

## Update

I have found the following command in [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/rabbitmq-users/rpO3dFzm-yQ) thread:

```
rabbitmqctl eval 'Q = {resource, <<"/">>, queue, <<"sharding: sharded_queue - rabbit@hostname - 0">>}, rabbit_amqqueue:internal_delete(Q).'
```

This actually deletes the queue. It doesn't show up anymore in the GUI. However the disk space is still not freed up which is a huge problem.